# How to pass a variable by reference to an event handler in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I simulated a class in JavaScript; it's code is here:

```
function myclass()
{
    this.count ;

    this.init = function(){
        $("div.mybtn").click({n:this},function(e){
            e.data.n.count++;
        });
    }

    this.getCount = function(){
        alert(this.count);
    }
}
```

Then I created an instance of this class and executed it's method `init()`, but when I click on any `div.mybtn` element, it did not increment the value of `this.count`.
It seems the object `this` was passed to event handler by value not by reference.
How I can pass a variable to an event handler by reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have pass-by-reference parameters. For what you want, you should use a closure variable:

```
this.init = function(){
    var self = this;
    $("div.mybtn").click(function(){
        self.count++;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't increment `undefined`, you have to start somewhere:

```
function myclass() {
    this.count=0;   // start counting at zero !!!

    this.init = function(){
        $("div.mybtn").on('click', {n:this},function(e){
            e.data.n.count++;
            e.data.n.getCount();
        });
    }

    this.getCount = function(){
        console.log(this.count);
    }
}

var c = new myclass();

c.init()
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgrDN/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bind function and bind the context with the event handler.

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift();

    return function(){
        fn.apply(object, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    }
}

function myclass()
{
    this.count ;

    this.clicked = function(){
        this.count++;    
    };

    this.init = function(){
        $("div.mybtn").click(this.clicked.bind(this));
    }

    this.getCount = function(){
        alert(this.count);
    }
}
```